# ActionBarSherlock Type mAdded cannot be resolved or is not a field Watson.java

Tags: java, android, eclipse, actionbarsherlock

I spended a day looking for solution for this error
I downloaded [ActionBarSherlock](http://ActionBarSherlock.com) and import library to eclipse
I had fixed all errors and this is the last one
I Checked all layouts there is no xml error, Cleaned workspace and restarted eclipse

this is error descrition :

> Description   Resource Path Location Type mAdded cannot be resolved or
>   is not a
>   field Watson.java /abs_library/src/android/support/v4/app line 59 Java
>   Problem

The code

```
if (mFragments.mAdded != null) {
                for (int i = 0; i < mFragments.mAdded.size(); i++) {
                    Fragment f = mFragments.mAdded.get(i);
                    if (f != null && !f.mHidden && f.mHasMenu && f.mMenuVisible
                            && f instanceof OnCreateOptionsMenuListener) {
                        show = true;
                        ((OnCreateOptionsMenuListener) f).onCreateOptionsMenu(
                                menu, inflater);
                        if (newMenus == null) {
                            newMenus = new ArrayList<Fragment>();
                        }
                        newMenus.add(f);
                    }
                }
            }
```

Thank you

Comment: ActionBarSherlock is deprecated. Eclipse ADT plugin is deprecated.

Comment: @JaredBurrows what do you mean ?

Comment: Why are you using `ActionBarSherlock`? It is 2015, you should be using AppCompat, just like Jake Wharton tells you to: https://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock.

Comment: Thanks didn't notice that

Comment: I'm using ActionBarSherlock because I have legacy code that requires it. I've begun the process of converting to AppCompat, but am currently stuck, after having completed almost all the conversion. That's why I need a "quick fix" to this problem: after that, I can resume work on the conversion.

Answer (score 4):

if you updated your android-support-v4.jar, just replace these three lines of code

```
if (mFragments.mAdded != null) {
   for (int i = 0; i < mFragments.mAdded.size(); i++) {
      Fragment f = mFragments.mAdded.get(i);
```

with

```
List<Fragment> actives =  mFragments.getActiveFragments(null);
if (actives != null) {
   for (int i = 0; i < actives.size(); i++) {
       Fragment f = actives.get(i);
```

...

everything will be ok.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution:
1# download SherlockActionBar sources from here:
https://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock/releases
2# if you're using android-support-v4.jar in your project (as I am) -> replace it from ZIP #1 (you can find it in 'libs' folder)
It helps me.

Note:
I had 2 versions of android-support-v4.jar in my project:

1. from AndroidSDK (extras~>android~>v4) // *work with the error*
2. from SherlockActionBar // *works ok here*